# Login with JDBC Realm in GlassFish 4.1 / Java EE 7

Tags: jakarta-ee, authentication, glassfish, java-ee-7, jdbcrealm

I want to use java security using JDBC realm for logging and authority.
I use GlassFish server 4.1 and do all of config related to JDBC realm, Data source and connection pool.Also i config web.xml and sun-web.

I create two tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE USERS (
  `USERID` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `PASSWORD` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`USERID`)
);

CREATE TABLE USERS_GROUPS (
  `GROUPID` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `USERID` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`GROUPID`)
);
```

I think I do all of required changes but when I login,every time it goes to login error page

My Jdbc Relam:

[image]

sha algorithm that i used:

```
 try {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        String text = "admin";
        md.update(text.getBytes("UTF-8")); // Change this to "UTF-16" if needed
        byte[] digest = md.digest();
        BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(1, digest);
        String output = bigInt.toString(16);

        System.out.println(output);

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(PasswordTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

There is not a field called username in the USERS table and groupname in the GROUPS table but you refer them in the JDBC realm administration. Or refer to userid and groupid or change the field names to username and groupname.